# Flutter: It's possible to send data from Android module to Flutter project via MethodChannel without close Activity(Still in Android Activity)?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I have screens.

1. StoryScreen (from Flutter)
2. MainActivity (from Android Activity, extend to FlutterActivity)
3. MainUnityActivity (from Android Activity, extend to AppCompatActivity)

The actually screen is only two, `StoryScreen` and `MainUnityActivity`. `MainActivity` only for host.

In `MainActivity` we define `intent` and `method channel`.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val tag = "MAIN"
    private val channel = "NATIVE_EXPERIMENT"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor, channel).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method.equals("goToUnityActivity")) {
                val arg = call.arguments as Map<String, Any>
                val gameType = arg.getValue("gameType") as String
                val catalogURL = arg.getValue("catalogURL") as String
                goToUnityActivity(gameType, catalogURL)
                result.success(null)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun goToUnityActivity(gameType: String, catalogURL: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainUnityActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("gameType", gameType)
        intent.putExtra("catalogURL", catalogURL)
        startActivityForResult(intent, MainUnityActivity.REQUEST_CODE_FROM_UNITY)
    }

    private fun notifyFlutterBackFromUnity(data: String?) {
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine?.dartExecutor, channel).invokeMethod("backFromUnity", data)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == MainUnityActivity.REQUEST_CODE_FROM_UNITY) {
            if (resultCode == MainUnityActivity.RESULT_CODE_BACK_FROM_UNITY) {
                val listOfReport = data!!.getStringExtra("listOfReport")
                Log.i(tag, "/// [MainActivity] back from unity --> $listOfReport")
                notifyFlutterBackFromUnity(listOfReport)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I exit from `MainUnityActivity`, I can send data from Android to Flutter side, but how if we still in `MainUnityActivity` but want to send data from Android to Flutter side?

```kotlin
class MainUnityActivity : UnityPlayerActivity() {
    private val tag = "MIDDLEWARE_UNITY"
    private val listOfVehicleNames: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    companion object {
        const val RESULT_CODE_BACK_FROM_UNITY = 110
        const val REQUEST_CODE_FROM_UNITY = 1
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        listOfVehicleNames.clear()
    }

    private fun backFromUnity() {
        Log.i(tag, "/// [MainUnityActivity] BackButtonClick")
        val resultIntent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra("listOfReport", listOfVehicleNames.toString())
        }
        setResult(RESULT_CODE_BACK_FROM_UNITY, resultIntent)
        finish()
    }

    override fun BackButtonClick() {
        Log.i(tag, "/// [MainUnityActivity] BackButtonClick")
        backFromUnity()
    }

    override fun ReportButtonClick() {
        Log.i(tag, "/// [MainUnityActivity] ReportButtonClick")
        showDialog()
    }

    private fun notifyFlutterReportFromUnity() {
        val json = """{"title": "JSON Title", "notes": "JSON Notes"}"""
        Log.i(tag, "/// [MainUnityActivity] YesReportClick :$json")
        listOfVehicleNames.add(json)
        // TODO: I want send data to Flutter without close this activity
    }

    private fun showDialog() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Report")
        builder.setMessage("Is there something wrong ?")

        builder.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes"
        ) { _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Okay, we're sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            notifyFlutterReportFromUnity()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton(
            "No"
        ) { _, _ ->
            // User click no
        }

        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
        builder.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RYlzNGZiOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fix it using `MethodChannel`, `EventChannel`, and `BroadcastReceiver`.

> Method channel: A named channel for communicating with platform plugins using asynchronous method calls.

> Event Channel: A named channel for communicating with platform plugins using event streams.

The example project is here: https://github.com/rrifafauzikomara/example_flutter_method_channel